# How to Calculate avg no of records added per day in BigQuery.?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in `BigQuery` having a column *Published_date* with a datatype of "Timestamp". I want to calculate avg no of rows added per day (for a specific month) in that table. I have the following query

```
SELECT AVG(Num_Rows) 
FROM (SELECT [Day]=DAY( Published_Date ), Num_Rows=COUNT(*)
FROM `mytable`
WHERE Published_Date BETWEEN '20190729' AND '20190729 '
GROUP BY DAY( Published_Date ) ) AS Z
```

But its generating the following error

> Could not cast literal "20190729" to type TIMESTAMP

How should I deal with timestamp because I only need the date from `timestamp` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to calculate avg no of rows added per day (for a specific month) in that table

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AVG(Num_Rows) AS avg_rows_per_day
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(Published_Date) AS day, COUNT(*) AS Num_Rows
  FROM `project.dataset.mytable`
  WHERE DATE(Published_Date) BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
  GROUP BY day
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit conversion:

```
WHERE Published_Date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-07-29') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-07-29')
```

Note that you have a column called "_date", but the error is saying that the value is a timestamp.  I find this confusing.  We use a convention of using `_ts` in columns that are `timestamps` (and `_dt` for `datetime` and `_date` for `date`).

Why is this important?  The timestamp is UTC.  So you might need to be careful about timezones and time components -- which is not obvious in a column called `Publish_Date`.

Comment: thank you ...
But then how will I group by day?...I used explicit conversion as you mentioned but now its generating following error.." Unrecognized name: Day" in line 2 of my query..how should i deal with it ?

Comment: "2019-10-21 17:31:00 UTC " that how column values look like....how should i group by day?. As i want avg no of rows added per day for a specific month ...

Comment: @MuhammadAqeel . . . Use `DATE()` instead of `DAY()`.